# "Chained" basis theorem: why a function is an isomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

I'm following a course whose topic is Brower's degree, and I can't undestand a part of the proof (given by the teacher) of the following theorem, which is fundamental for the development of the theory:

> Let $v:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ a curve of class $C^1$ such that $v(t) \neq 0$ for every $t \in [a,b]$ and let $(v(a),z_1,\dots,z_n)$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$.
>
> Then there are $N$ curves $\beta_j:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{N+1} \ (j=1,\dots,N)$ of class $C^1$ such that the n-tuple $(v(t),\beta_1(t), \dots,\beta_N(t))$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ for every $t \in [a,b],$ and that for $t=a$ it coincides with $(v(a),z_1,\dots,z_n)$

Proof: consider, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}$, the differential equation (which has a unique solution) $$\left\{
                \begin{array}
                  \ U'_x(t)=<U_x(t),\frac{v(t)}{|v(t)|^2}> v'(t)\\ 
U_x(a)=x
                \end{array}
              \right.$$
where $<\ ,\ >$ denotes the standart scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}.
$ Now,  let's call $S(t,x)=U_x(t)$ (where $U_x(t)$ is the unique solution of the equation): for every $t \in [a,b],\ S(t,.):\mathbb{R}^{N+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ is an isomorphism and thus maps bases into bases, and $S(a,.)$ is the identity. It is then sufficient to put $\beta_j(t)=S(t,z_j)$ for $t \in [a,b]$ and $j=1, \dots,N$ to obtain the curves with the desired properties.

I don't understand why the map $S(t,.):\mathbb{R}^{N+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ is an isomorphism. I can accept its linearity but I truly don't see why it is bijective. Thank you to everybody.

Comment: I don't see it either, but I haven't looked at it for long. But I have a suggestion: let $v(t)  = (\cos t, \sin t) \in \Bbb R^2$, and see what $U_x$ looks like by integrating the differential equation by hand. It may suddenly become obvious. I suspect that in general, you'll find that if $<x_1, x_2> = 0$, then $U_{x_1}(t)$ and $U_{x_2}(t)$ are also perpendicular; at that point it should all be obvious. Certainly you should be able to check that $S(t, \cdot)$ has the property that $S(t, cv) = c S(t, v)$, where $c$ is a scalar, and that's HALF of proving linearity...

Comment: Thanks! Now I'll try to make some calculations and see what happens. Let me know if you have new ideas.

Comment: It has an obvious time-reversal inverse.

Comment: Ok you're right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever theorem you use to construct $S(t,.)$ (e.g. Picard iteration) also allows you to construct its inverse by reversing the role of $a$ and $t$.

Comment: That makes it a bijection on $\Bbb R^n$, but that doesn't mean that the derivative is nonzero (consider $x \mapsto x^3$ on $\Bbb R$, which is bijective and has an inverse, but zero derivative at $x = 0$. Hence you haven't proved that the function maps bases to bases.

Comment: @JohnHughes: the questioner is happy with the linearity of $S(t,.)$ - the question is simply whether the map has an inverse, which I am saying follows by symmetry. This question is purely about linear maps.

Comment: *If* you know it's linear, then invertibility follows from what you said. If I were OP, I might start doubting hat linearity is all that easy (indeed, even though I've thought about it for a while, it's still not completely clear to me). "I can accept its linearity" didn't read to me like a ringing confidence in the matter, so I wanted to point out that without that confidence, your answer wasn't enough. (I should have mentioned that I *liked* the answer, BTW, but I don't think that "reversing the role of $a$ and $t$" is the right thing to do: one is a  scalar and one's a point in $\Bbb R^n$.)

Comment: What's wanted, I think, is to simply negate $t$, holding $a$ fixed, but I could be wrong about that.